# Gizmo constraints are not constraining?

Tags: constraints, axis

I've been using the bleeding edge 2.8 builds and downloading the latest build every day from Blender.org. On top of this, I've also been heavily tweaking shortcuts and trying to get myself as comfortable as I have been in 2.79. Things have been going great, but just in the last day or two, I've noticed this, and wonder if it's because of a new build bug, or if I've made a tweak too far and broken something for myself??...
So the gizmo axis constraints, X,Y,Z, the arrows - they don't constrain any more. Dragging the blue Z arrow will not, for example, constrain the objects movement in the Z axis.
Can anyone who has a build from 18th or 19th December please confirm for me that this works in their version? Also, is there any way that anyone knows of that I could've accidentally disabled the constraining behaviour of the gizmos? I've not heard of any way myself, but you never know?
Thanks for listening!!
Wayne

...ok, answered this for myself - was totally my fault, but maybe worth mentioning for future fiddlers...

It was OpenGL Depth Picking in User Preferences. I had messed with the Selection: section of the General Preferences. The result of this was not only that the constraints weren't constraining, also I was unable to select any object with the mouse! So, I put the setting back where they should be ('Automatic' and OpenGL Depth Picking ON) and all is right with the world again!

Comment: I don't see this as a suitable question for this platform. Builds from few days ago are not available for downloads any more - this is completely irrelevant already and it is only 10 minutes after you asked. Gizmos work in the latest build. It is not a good idea to start customizing yet. Changes in Blender might not be compatable with your saved user preferences. My first step in troubleshooting would be to delete the preferences folder. This means you will lose the customizations you just made.I would advise to wait until it is released. Beta is for testing. Plese do that - test.